# How to include one header for every page in different folders

Tags: php

How can I use one header.php file for every html page in different folders?

For example:

My **header.php** file is in **homepage/includes folder**.

And i include like this **include "includes/header.php";**

*up to now, everything is okay.*

And i have a diffent folder on my homepage called **"users"**

And i wanna include my **header.php** file, which is on **homepage/includes** folder, on **homepage/users/index.php** file.

And i include like this "include **"../includes/header.php"**, but I have errors.

Cause on my header.php file I call my css files like **`<link href="assets/css/demo.css"/>`**

So I need to copy my **header.php** file to **users folder**.

And I need to change **href="assets/...."** like **href="../assets/...."**

Isn't there any way to solve it?? Thank you.

Comment: *How can I use one header.php file for every html page in different folders?* A HTML file can't run a PHP file in a standard configuration.

Answer (score 1):

append the line to all php files which require the header

Note: please use the correct path in `file_location/header.php`

```
<?php
include_once('header.php');
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer OP is looking for. As I read it it's about file paths.

Answer (score 0):

First of the wall, you can create `config.php` file with global variables to all of your php files which needs that variables. Put it in the main folder of your project and include it in any file you need.

Then, you can define `$path = '/absolute/path/to/your/project';` variable in your `config.php` and use it when you need. Then, if you ever will need to change this path value, you only should change value of that variable.

At the other hand, it is an magic constant `__DIR__` (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), which return absolute path to file with it (if you use this constant in `includes/header.php` it will return `/path/to/homepage/includes/`, but if you use it in `users/index.php` it will return `/path/to/homepage/users/`).

In this case it should work, when you type `include __DIR__.'../includes/header.php';`, but I recommend to solve your problem in the first way, because if structure of your project will be changed, you must change any file with those lines in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is `relative` vs `absolute` paths.

When using `require_once` you can use a constant defined in your `index.php` or inside a `config.php` or `setup.php` depending on your application. It would look something like:

```
require_once APP_PATH . 'includes/header.php';
```

In your case APP_PATH could be defined as the full path before the include, ie. `define('APP_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');` or if you want to hardcode it `define('APP_PATH', '/home/www/my-app/');`

You can use the absolute path to your css files for the assets to work,

```
<link href="/assets/css/demo.css"/>
```

OR for better portability you can create a little function to wrap all style calls:

```
<link href="<?php echo css_asset('demo.css'); ?>"/>

// Then the possible definition of css could be
function css_asset($style)
{
    return '/assets/css/' . $style;
}
```